# Inheriting / Extending sharing rules on a custom object

Tags: security, sharing, apex-managed-sharing, criteria-based-sharing, sharing-sets

Here is my scenario,

[image]

**GroupAccount** - (ORG wide READ permission)

- A custom object which is parent object of Account (standard)
- One GA can have many Accounts

**Account** - (ORG wide - Private)(Has sharing rules)

**Document__c**
A custom object which has Many to Many relationship with Group Account Object

**GroupAccount_Document__c** 
A junction object with many to many relationship between GroupAccount and Document__c

**Requirement**
When user goes to view GroupAccount data then i should be able to show Document__c records based on the below condition
 - All Document records related to that GroupAccount if User has access to even one Account Record of that GroupAccount

**My questions are**
 - How to implement Sharing rules for this scenario. For e.g. if i run a SOQL like "Select documents from GroupAccount junction object where GroupAccount=XXX" then user should get documents related to this GroupAccount only if he has access to one of Accounts of that GroupAccount

I have updated my question based on change in design. I am not a Salesforce expert so excuse me if my question is dumb.

Comment: I assume your "Accounts" is the standard Account object, You do not have access to Document__c via the junction object (Until its master detail) or you cannot control access to Account through groupAccount__c, I suggest you can use apex manage sharing to dynamically share the records on certain conditions.

Comment: If you are talking about SOQL query as you mentioned in your comment  SELECT Document from account.... Apex runs on system context and it will return the data based on this you can use apex sharing rule to share the data with any user.